# 30% of the 20 people in the Math Club have blonde hair.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

30% of the 20 people in the Math Club have blonde hair. If 3 people are selected at random from the club, what is the probability that none have blonde hair? Is this a combination and permutation math problem? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, that's one way of solving the problem. I think the probles statement would be clearer if it were stated as "Six of the 20 people in the Math Club have blond hair (...)". You could think, how many ways are there of selecting three people, and how many ways are there of selecting three people that have blonde hair.

Comment: I’m still confused??

Comment: I’m confused. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Hint: The probability is the ratio of "favored events" to "total possible events". You can coun't each of them with the binomial coefficient. Keep in mind, that $\binom{n}{r}$ is the number of $r$-subsets of a $n$-set.

Answer (score 3):

As Matti P commented, there are $6$ people in Math Club with blonde hair.

It is actually more difficult to calculate the probability that you pick someone with blonde hair, as you have to count whether you picked $1$, $2$, or even $3$ people with blonde hair.

It is easier to directly count the ways that you can pick three people that don't have blonde hair, and divide it by the total number of ways to pick three people from the club.

> You should get $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{14}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}$ as your answer, where $\binom{n}{r}$ is $n$ choose $r$.

Comment: This is not a permutation problem.

Comment: But it is the correct answer... (+1).

Comment: I’m still confused???

Comment: One way of seeing this problem is to realise that when you have $20$ people, and you choose three of them, there are ${ 20 \choose 3} = 1~140$ ways of doing this. These are $1~140$ distinct selections, or entities. You can think of if like $1~140$ coloured furry animals. When you make a random selection (three out of 20 people), it's the same as choosing **one** of these furry animals. Think about this for a while and convince yourself of this.

The next step is to look for a certain characteristic of these furry animals and ask: How many of these furry animals have this characteristic?

Comment: @Emily The number $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n - k)!}$, read "$n$ choose $k$", is the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set of $n$ elements.  Our sample space consists of the $\binom{20}{3}$ ways of choosing a subset of three people from the $20$ people in the math club.  Since we want the probability that none of the selected people have blonde hair, the favorable cases consist of the $\binom{14}{3}$ ways of selecting three people from the $14$ people in the math club who do not have blonde hair.